# Why I can't find any selector with Xpath using two classes

Tags: scrapy

I got a html page like this

```
<li class="class1 class2"></li>
```

but I try to find this selector by using

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="class1 class2"]')
```

I always got None.
I also try to run this code:

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="class1"]')
response.xpath('//li[@class="class1 class2"]')
```

Both return None

Who can tell me what's wrong?

Maybe I resolved but I don't understand. I found a phenomenon that I use DevTools on Chrome, that shows like this `<li class="class1 class2"><\li>`. But I use scrapy to crawl and return `<li class="class1 class2 class3"><\li>`
I encountered some phenomenon that the web page source code is different from the source code I crawled.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is your `<li><\li>` is not valid HTML like `<li></li>` and `xpath` should look like:

```
.//li[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]
```

May use a tool like [xpather](http://xpather.com/XrAxTIeC) to check if a path works or not.